# How to save and load monitor configurations with Gnome?

Tags: gnome, display

I have two monitors, one attached to my personal desktop and another attached to both my work and personal desktop.

Every day in the morning I use Gnome's "Display" menu to set a monitor arrangement (mirrored) while I'm at work, and at the end of the workday I use it again to set it to a different arrangement (extended). I do this because I uss a USB switch to move my keyboard between the two computers, and I don't want applications on the smaller monitor running my personal desktop to get lost on the monitor set to my work desktop, so I just set it to mirrored.

This is annoying to do repeatedly. Is there a way to save these settings and then quickly switch between them with a command?

Comment: xorg or Wayland?